# MYSQLI row updating by 2 when update by 1 is called

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a curious problem. When i make an update to a row, the info is updated, but not how i expect it to. i call this code

```
$count = $v_count+1;
mysqli_query($db_conn, "UPDATE videos SET v_count='$count' WHERE id='$vk'");
```

I have also tried this code as well...

```
if(isset($_POST['vk'])){
mysqli_query($db_conn, "UPDATE videos SET v_count='$v_count'+1 WHERE id='$vk'");

}else{
echo mysqli_error($db_conn);exit();
}
```

It does work, But the number is increased by 2, not the 1 i expected.This line HAS worked in other applications i have used... but now it is behaving oddly. Any help will be appreciated.
   Here is the full PHP block

```
$vk = $_GET['vk'];
if($vk != ''){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id='$vk' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $sql) or die (mysqli_error()); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
$v_count            = $row['v_count'];
}
mysqli_query($db_conn, "UPDATE videos SET v_count=v_count+1 WHERE id='$vk'");
mysqli_free_result($query);
}else{
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Is the idea to increment `v_count` by 1 or is `v_count` an entirely different number from what is in the database?

Comment: where is `$v_count` coming from? Or try (cause I don't know the rest of your code) the second version adapted to: `SET v_count=v_count+1` - if that is what you wanna achieve!?

Comment: `$v_count` is being defined in a while loop above this code. like i said, it is working, but increases the count by 2, not the expected 1. @jsfan ,v_count is in the database, and every time the video is called, i want it to increase only by 1. Currently it is increasing By 2

Comment: Note: Numeric fields should not be enclosed in quotes in SQL

Comment: In that case you should increment in SQL as @Jeff suggested. Otherwise, you risk race conditions.

Comment: Is it possible that you created a trigger previously to also increase by 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some error in your application logic such that `$v_count` in your PHP code doesn't equal the `v_count` field in your MySQL table.

If you use

```
mysqli_query($db_conn, "UPDATE videos SET v_count=v_count+1 WHERE id='$vk'");
```

it will always increase by 1 no matter what the value of your $v_count PHP variable.

Comment: i inserted that line. it does increase the count, but by 2 instead of 1.

Comment: i have included the full codeblock to my question. It is the increase by 2 that baffles me....

Comment: No, this line increases the count by 1. If your count gets increased by 2 it is because you also increase it by 1 somewhere else in your code. Just to be sure... did you actually 'insert' the line? Because, you know, it was supposed to _replace_ what you had.

Comment: lol yes.. i replaced it. What you see in my edit is what is in my code. There is no other UPDATE, no other string manipulation. I take that line out, it does not increase.

Comment: Well, in that case the only thing that comes to mind is that the second increase is because your MySQL database has a trigger defined that increases the `v_count` field whenever the `video` table gets updated. You can run a `SHOW TRIGGERS;` query to make sure.

Comment: i voted yours as the correct answer,because it was. it just wasnt working on the same page, so i redirected to another page, where it DID update correctly, and redirected to the watch page. Now, everything works correctly. Thank you for your help, all.